# Scale Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT ) Implementation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I am trying to implement SIFT in matlab. I am following the Lowe's 2004 paper. I completed upto calculation of keypoints and assigning orientations to them.(i.e for all octaves). Here i got one doubt before implementing descriptors.. how I can find the descriptors for the keypoints in octaves of other size. ( If original image size is 256*256, the octaves of other size means like 128*128,64*64).

my approach is explained below.

1. Here I taken a 256*256 image and octaves as 256*256,128*128,64*64,32*32 images. In each octave 5 images (one original and 4 blurred images).
2. I calculated upto keypoints and orientations for all octaves. ( In this I have 2 images in each octave).
3. the keypoints in octaves of size 128*128, 64*64,32*32. If I want to represent these keypoints on an image of 256*256 image, how I can represent? (My doubt is for eg. 64*64 image has keypoints range upto (64,64) ).

   If the answer is interpolation of 64*64 image to 256*256. how keypoints(i.e location,scale and orientation) are interpolated?

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This may need to be retagged.  I'm not convinced that it's related to "-deployment", "-engine", "-standalone".  Instead, consider adding [computer-vision], [data-transformation] and other tags.  That way, you'll get more attention from the CV folks on SO.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Perhaps you could have somebody proofread and help you reword your question. It would help us give you a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you take a look at [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html)'s SIFT implementation (mex wrapper around C/C++ code). Dig into the source code to find what they're doing and why. Compare w/ Lowe's paper.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are referring actually. Is it that you are stuck in reproducing the sift code in matlab. If so, you actually no need to represent the keypoints present in a lower scale image to the original scale. The values are stored in a 'vector' along with the octave in which it is present. In the later stages of coding, the octave number can be used for further calculation and to perform matching function.

Comment: Thank you tikku.., yes I stuck in the implementation of SIFT in matlab. If it is possible can we contact through mail. My email is arunmanikumar@gmail.com